# Command-Left/Right Arrow key combo stops working after Lion upgrade

Tags: macos, keyboard, osx-lion

I posted this in the Apple support forums with no answer, so I'm hoping I'll be able to get one here.

I finally got around to upgrading my MacBook Pro to Lion, and one of the first things I've noticed is that my Command-Left Arrow/Right Arrow key combinations stopped working completely; no matter what application or context I try to use them in, they don't work at all.  In Snow Leopard, I used them primarily for moving to the beginning and end of a line in text apps (Komodo IDE, TextWrangler, etc.), changing rooms in Colloquy, and other things.  But no matter where I used them, the combination is not recognized. However, if I use them in combination with other keys, such as Option-Command-Right/Left Arrow or Shift-Command-Right/Left Arrow, they work fine.   As an example, if I go into my Komodo preferences and try to set a key binding for navigating to the end of a line, the key combination does not even register; but if I do Command-Alt-Right/Left Arrow, it registers fine. In web page textareas, however, even those combinations don't work. Command-Up/Down Arrow combos work fine, but nothing happens with left/right arrows.

In searching these forums and other places, I've seen remedies such as killing the dock (running "killall Dock" from Terminal), some swiping and re-selecting of apps from Mission Control, and other things that seem to have worked for other people with the same problem, but nothing has corrected the problem for me.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to correct this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 40):

Open a terminal and type `killall Dock`. It seems to be a bug with the Dock. After that the Dock will restart and you should have your shortcut back (I did!).

Comment: I would upvote more if I could. Thank you so much. This was so annoying

Comment: Thank you. It happened to me once and I found this question. Searched Google and found the solution so I answered :)

Comment: So basically turning it off and on again?

Comment: Yes. And since Mavericks and Yosemite, I no longer have found this issue.

Comment: I get this issue in Yosemite with my Mission Control space-switching keys, and `killall Dock` clears it up. It often seems to happen after I switch into the Dashboard screen.

Comment: I got this after trying to update the plist file to add new xcode key definitions and installing  an xcode plugin, after reverting all these changes still had the problem, but the killall dock did the trick for me. Have just reinstalled the plugin and it is fine.

Comment: This is happening occasionally on my 2020 Intel MBP 16" running MacOS 12.2 Monterrey. `killall Dock` still does the trick. Thanks @dresende!

Answer (score 4):

Check System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts to see if those key combinations have been assigned to some feature.

Comment: This suggestion worked for me. Mission control had option+left and option+right assigned to moving spaces. Very annoying.